# How to move a specific element to a specific index in python?

Tags: python, list

How do I move a specific element to a specific index in Python?

```
fruits = apple, cherry, durian, berry
```

How can I move `"berry"` to `fruits[1]`?

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: No, because this is not a list, this is a tuple, which is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

1. Find the index of `"berry"`, then `.pop()` it and `.insert()` it to index `1`.

   ```py
   fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "durian", "berry"]
   fruits.insert(1, fruits.pop(fruits.index("berry")))
   print(fruits)
   # ['apple', 'berry', 'cherry', 'durian']
   ```
2. `.remove()` it and `.insert()` it.

   ```py
   fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "durian", "berry"]
   fruits.remove("berry")
   fruits.insert(1, "berry")
   print(fruits)
   # ['apple', 'berry', 'cherry', 'durian']
   ```
3. swap the value of whatever is in index 1 and the index of `"berry"`.

   ```py
   fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "durian", "berry"]
   fruits[1], fruits[i] = fruits[i := fruits.index("berry")], fruits[1]
   print(fruits)
   # ['apple', 'berry', 'durian', 'cherry']
   ```

The last option works differently. It's faster as it doesn't have to move the elements to the right but the order may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, tuples are immutable structure. Once you create a tuple, its contents stay as they are, preventing accidental changes that might mess up your program. The Python interpreter won't allow you to modify it.

To get done what you want, just turn the tuple into a list, make your changes, and then turn it back into a tuple. For instance:

```
new_list = list(fruits)
new_list.insert(1, fruits[-1]) # inserting berry in position 1
del new_list[-1] # deleting the berry at last position
new_tuple = tuple(new_list) # contains a new tuple with the desired order.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = apple, cherry, durian, berry
```

this is a tuple and tuples are immutable which means that the contents in a tuple cannot be changed.

tuple syntax:-

```
 1. variable = (item1, item2, ..itemN)
    
    2. variable = item1, item2, ..itemN
```

but if there's a syntax mistake and you forget to put the square brackets then, this is how to you change a index of an element

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "durian", "berry"]

fruits.remove("berry")  # use remove to remove the element from the index
fruits.insert(1,"berry") #insert the element at your preferable location
print(fruits)
```

Answer (score -1):

look at index below:

```
fruits = [apple, cherry, durian, berry]
#          0        1      2       3
```

You can use .pop() to remove a specified index. i.e.

```
save_here = fruits.pop('berry')
```

This will remove berry and save the string into a variable

Once saved you can use .insert() i.e

```
fruit.insert(1, save_here)
```

print fruit and see the results!

Just another option in the bunch!